# Spring MVC boolean/radio button default value

Tags: spring-mvc, boolean

I am using a boolean in my Spring MVC form. However, when the form first displayed the boolean defaults to false. I want the boolean to be initialized to something equivalent to null, and stay that way until the user makes their choice.

Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

FYI: I don't want to use checkbox, or anything else. I would really prefer a radio button.

```
<springform:form>
    <springform:radiobutton value="1" />
    <springform:radiobutton value="0" />
<springform:form>
```

Comment: Could you post more of your JSP? In particular, posting the entire `<form>` element would he helpful so we can see everything that is going on.

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this is using Boolean class instead of boolean primitive. Boolean class has a default value of null so it is not initially set.